# basler camera automatic image adjustment function in ROS

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running Basler camera with ROS using package: pylon_camera for Basler cameras.
When run camera in a relatively dark environment, e.g. under a desk, the camera return a black image with most pixel value between 1 to 3. With camera's default API, the automatic image adjustment tool can return an image with reasonable pixel range and intensity.
Anyone knows if this automatic image adjustment function in which part of ROS package, or how to implement it?
Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289383/basler-camera-automatic-image-adjustment-function-in-ros/) by [CrystalJing](https://answers.ros.org/users/34777/crystaljing/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There appears to be an 'exposure_auto' parameter:
https://github.com/magazino/pylon_camera/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=exposure_auto

Also setting a fixed exposure manually (via a ros param) looks to be supported, and the exposure can be controlled live through the set_exposure service.

(I haven't personally tried either, it's just there in the source)

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CrystalJing](https://answers.ros.org/users/34777/crystaljing/) on 2018-04-23**:
yes, in that way it works if also set up a brightness parameter